# error while using openstack cli

Tags: openstack, identity

Failed to discover available identity versions when contacting http://127.0.0.1:60999/v2.0/. Attempting to parse version from URL.

> Unauthorized (HTTP 401)

Comment: what i have to do in this case?why this error?

Comment: what exact CLI command you are using? And have you sourced your creds?